# Programmer with mobile and Full stack development experience, what is the name?

Tags: resume, skills

Hope its a right place for asking this type of question, if not, please point to right place.

Here we go ..

Lets say a programmer has skills in mobile applications development (like `Android`, `iOS`) and also in Front-end / Back-end web development (like `Angular`, `Node.js` and `PHP` + `MongoDB`). In all areas he has experience from 3-5 years.

So what sort of developer is he?

- Some people say: *Full-stack developer* that covers  Front-end / Back-end developer.
- Some people say: *Senior developer* but for me it doesn't make sense because 12 years as `.Net` developer is also *Senior*

**Senior Mobile and Full-stack developer?** it seems messy

Can someone spread the light on this issue?

Comment: The general case is answered on the post David linked. Specific titles are usually off-topic here. VTC

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when building my CV, and solved it using a "speciality" line. Typically, your job title would look like

> **Full stack developer**
>
> Specialist in mobile development

I would avoid to put "senior" in the title as this is covered by experience, and doesn't explain what is the profession of the candidate.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the other answers, if this is someone who has wide ranging experience in different languages, and likely not to be limited to that either i.e. her/his scope may grow with need if projects they work on come to require it, I would simply call her/him:

**Developer**

Reason being that they need to develop using a language and tools that achieve a given project's deliverable. It is only in their *roles* on a particular project that specifics of what they will specialize shall be fully described.

This is different from someone like:

`SQL Developer, Mobile Developer, VB Developer, or Web Developer`

Because these have limited scope, and only likely to grow within the field prefixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Full Stack Web & App Developer" because just Full Stack + mobile would still read as just Web to me personally. App development tends to be called out separately. If I just saw "mobile", I'd think responsive websites etc.

Comment: There might not be need to be specific about it, when the work is likely general.